# Where do I find the Greater Glyph of Igni diagram?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Where do I find the Greater Glyph of Igni diagram?
I heard you can find them in Skellige.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [/u/jmarFTL on /r/Witcher](http://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/37i1fk/psa_where_to_find_greater_glyph_diagrams/), you can find a merchant selling the various Greater Glyph diagrams in a monster-infested village on the east side of the lake between Crossroads and Blandare.

[image]
Thanks to [/u/Telescopy](http://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/37i1fk/psa_where_to_find_greater_glyph_diagrams/crmv9gb) for the image (will replace with better image shortly).

Simply clear the area of monsters, and visit the merchant during the day.

Comment: Hmmm weird I liberated the town where your green marker is and I found people there but the two houses you marked are empty. Maybe you need to do a quest before they arrive?

Comment: Apologies, not the location of the green marker, where the cursor/red circle is.

Comment: The merchant doesn't sell it. Maybe you need to complete the main story line first?

Comment: The link above also mentions that the merchant only sells it during the day, or after a period of time. But I guess it could also be progress related (or level related)

Answer (score 4):

I got the Greater Glyph of Igni diagram, Greater Glyph of Axii diagram and Greater Glyph of Aard diagram from the armorer in Larvik, to the east of Lofoten.

He says something like "Don't skimp on the armor"

Greater Glyph of Yrden diagram & Greater Glyph of Quen diagram:
The merchant at the sawmill to the north east of Rannvaig (you need to liberate the area first).

In related news, the following rune diagrams can be found on the blacksmith in Arinbjorn, third house from the coast:

- Greater Rune of dazhbog Diagram
- Greater Rune of devana Diagram
- Greater Rune of zoria Diagram
- Greater Rune of morana Diagram
- Greater Rune of triglav Diagram